Variable transformation in the definite integral
recently I encounter a variable transformation problem in the derivation and I did not figure out how it works.
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\rho^2}\{s\rho^2C(\textbf{r}_2,ss^\prime\rho)\}dsds^\prime=\int_0^1ds\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{d}{ds}\frac{1}{\rho}\int_0^1ds^\prime\frac{d}{ds^\prime}\{ss^\prime\rho^2C(\textbf{r}_2,ss^\prime\rho)\}$$
How did he achieve it directly? I have thought it over for quite a long time but does not have ideas. Thanks
Here are some attempts for deriving the final expression. I have no ideas where it is wrong.
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\rho^2}\{s\rho^2C(\textbf{r}_2,ss^\prime\rho)\}dsds^\prime=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{s{s^\prime}^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\rho^2}\{s^2{s^\prime}^2\rho^2C(\textbf{r}_2,ss^\prime\rho)\}dsds^\prime$$
$$=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\partial}{\partial\rho}\{\frac{1}{s{s^\prime}^2}\frac{s^\prime}{\rho}\frac{\partial}{\partial s^\prime}[s^2{s^\prime}^2\rho^2C(\textbf{r}_2,ss^\prime\rho)]\}dsds^\prime$$
$$=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{s^\prime}\frac{\partial}{\partial\rho}\{\frac{1}{\rho s}\frac{\partial}{\partial s^\prime}[s^2{s^\prime}^2\rho^2C(\textbf{r}_2,ss^\prime\rho)]\}dsds^\prime$$
$$=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{s^\prime}\frac{s}{\rho}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\{\frac{1}{\rho s}\frac{\partial}{\partial s^\prime}[s^2{s^\prime}^2\rho^2C(\textbf{r}_2,ss^\prime\rho)]\}dsds^\prime$$
$$=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{s}{s^\prime}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\{\frac{\partial}{\partial s^\prime}[s{s^\prime}^2C(\textbf{r}_2,ss^\prime\rho)]\}dsds^\prime$$

$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\rho^2}\{s\rho^2C(\textbf{r}_2,ss^\prime\rho)\}dsds^\prime=\\
\frac{d}{d \rho} \int_0^1 \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \rho} \int_0^1 s \rho^2 C(\mathbf{r}_2, ss' \rho) \, ds \right) ds'
$$
If $u=s \rho$
$$
\frac{d}{d \rho} \int_0^1 \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \rho} \int_0^1 s \rho^2 C(\mathbf{r}_2, ss' \rho) \, ds \right) ds'=\\
\frac{d}{d \rho} \int_0^1 \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \rho} \int_0^\rho u C(\mathbf{r}_2, us' ) \, du \right) ds'
$$
By FTOC
$$
\frac{d}{d \rho} \int_0^1 \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \rho} \int_0^\rho u C(\mathbf{r}_2, us' ) \, du \right) ds'=\\
\frac{d}{d \rho} \int_0^1 \left( \rho C(\mathbf{r}_2, \rho s') \right) ds'
$$
If $u=s' \rho$
$$
\frac{d}{d \rho} \int_0^\rho C(\mathbf{r}_2, u) \, du
$$
Again by the FTOC
$$
\frac{d}{d \rho} \int_0^\rho C(\mathbf{r}_2, u) \, du= C(\mathbf{r}_2, \rho)
$$
But
$$
C(\mathbf{r}_2, \rho)=\int_0^1 \frac{d}{ds'}(s'C(\mathbf{r}_2, s' \rho) )\, ds'=\int_0^1\frac{d}{ds}(s \int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial s'}(s'C(\mathbf{r}_2, ss' \rho) )\, ds')ds=\\
\int_0^1ds\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{d}{ds}\frac{1}{\rho}\int_0^1ds^\prime\frac{\partial}{\partial s'}\{ss^\prime\rho^2C(\textbf{r}_2,ss^\prime\rho)\
$$

Thanks! I think I have understand your steps here!

I haven't checked for correctness, but the idea is to rewrite is by substitution
$$s' \rho\to u, \quad d\rho \to \frac{1}{s'} \ du, \quad  \partial_\rho \to s'\ \partial_{(s'* \rho)}  . $$
For a complete check factor out expressions independent of the integration variables $s,s'$, especially $\rho$, expand all integrals of sums, and with $F=\int f(s)\,ds$ use
$$\int_0^1 \ s' \  f'(\rho \  s \   s') \  ds' \ \to \  \frac{1}{\rho \ s}\ \left( f(\rho \ s) \ - \ f(0) \ - \frac{1}{\rho \  s} \ \left( F(\rho \ s)-F(0) \right)\right)$$
Since the art of the algebraic manipulations of substitutions in multiple integrals - before Grassmann - was considered to be the top qualification of a mathematician, better use automatic replacement by linearity.
First define in Mathematica in integral container, that prints by Leibniz representation, but is inactive
   Format[int[f_, dom_]] := HoldForm[Integrate[f, dom]]

Define linearity expansion functions, distribute $\int dx$ additive
   replPlus =
    Function[expr,
      ReplaceRepeated[
        expr, {int[a_Plus, b_] :> Map[Function[itgr, int[itgr, b] , a]]}]]

$$\int \text{a$\_$Plus} \, d\text{b$\_$}:\to \text{Map}[\text{Function}[\text{itgr},\int \text{itgr} \, db],a]$$
and in short notation, extract factors free of the local variable of integration
  replFac = (# //. {int[ a__*f__, {b_, c_,d_}] :> 
               a int[Times[  f], {b, c,d}] /; (FreeQ[a, b])} &)

$$\int[a_ {\_\ \_}  \ f_{\_\ \_}, \{b_{\_},\ c_{\_},d_{\_}\} :\to \
a \int[\text{Times}[f],\{b,c,d\}]/; (\text{FreeQ[a,b]}\&)$$
The retainment of the integrand by "Times" is crucial, without a product with more than one factor  is converted into a Sequence with rather funny effects.
With these expansions the left expression yields
$$\rho ^2 \left(\int_0^1 t^2 \int_0^1 s^3 f''(s t \rho ) \, ds \, dt\right)+4 \rho  \left(\int_0^1 t \int_0^1 s^2 f'(s t \rho ) \, ds \, dt\right)+2 \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 s f(s t \rho ) \, ds\right) \, dt$$
and the right expression
$$\rho ^2 \left(\int_0^1 s^2 \int_0^1 t^2 f''(s t \rho ) \, dt \, ds\right)+3 \rho  \left(\int_0^1 s \int_0^1 t f'(s t \rho ) \, dt \, ds\right)+\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 f(s t \rho ) \, dt\right) \, ds$$
with no checks done.
Test such doubious equalities  numerically first, using a random polynomial with NIntegrate.
  f[x_] =Sum[RandomReal[] x^n,{n,-1,3} ] Exp[-x^2] 


Hi, Following your clues $du = \frac{ds^\prime}{\rho}$, I tried some steps and posted it here. While I am not sure where it is wrong during my steps, I still cannot obtain the paper's form. Could you please help to have a check?

Hi, I have uploaded my attempts on the derivation. Thx~
